# Put whole gitlab installation to read-only mode

Tags: gitlab

I wish to deny to push changes to any repository by any user. Technically, I need to switch whole gitlab to read-only mode. 
Is there simple way to do this?

Comment: You want this read-only mode only for push, or for all any other actions in gitlab ? Setting user's access level to "Guest" or "Reporter" can help you (see [Gitlab's permissions](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/permissions/permissions.md)). But the VonC's solution is easier/quicker I think

Comment: Guests can still create issues and leave comments. Reporters can do slightly more. @jeanMarcAssin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to mess with the user privileges ([as done in this PR](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/7450/files)), one approach would be to change the [gitlab-shell pre-receive hook](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/blob/master/hooks/pre-receive).

If the pre-receive hook always "`exit 1`", that should disable any push to any repo.

Comment: I found another ugly but working method:

`# chmod -R -w gitlab-repositories-directory`

It's kind of shameful, but it's work.

Comment: @SemyonNovikov indeed. I guess the cleanest solution would be, as mentioned by  jeanMarcAssin, to bulk-change the user's access level (with a similar routine as the one I mentioned in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/7450/files)

Comment: This only prevents code changes from being made... you can still create non-code items (MRs, discussions, wiki pages, issues, etc.)

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean Agreed. Hence the top comment "You want this read-only mode only for push, or for all any other actions in gitlab ?". I will assume here this was just about the code.

Answer (score 8):

Actually a better answer is to change [this flag to true](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/16-5-stable/lib/gitlab/database.rb?ref_type=heads#L317). This makes the entire instance read only and adds a nice header in the app.

Comment: The code has changed since this post was made. Just to be explicit to save someone else the time...the code you are looking for is in the  `def self.read_only?` function. Just change it from `false` to `true`. On an Omnibus install the database.rb file will be in `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database.rb`, change the option and then run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and then `gitlab-ctl restart` and you are good to go.

Comment: you're my hero @KevinVasko none of the other methods (gitlab maintenance from gui nor rails console worked), I'm upgrading a very old gitlab instance, 14.5.2 the documentation says that Maintenance mode was introduced in GitLab 13.9 but in my case it isn't present. Changing the variable to true turns maintenance up, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

GitLab can be put in Maintenance Mode https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/maintenance_mode/

Note that it is only possible for the "Paid" self-managed tiers

> On GitLab self-managed, available in Premium and Ultimate. Not available on GitLab SaaS.

Answer (score 2):

I would be inclined to archive every project, which would prevent any changes (including to the wiki, issues, etc.).

[image]

Although, that doesn’t prevent new projects.

Comment: Be aware that archiving a project prevents it from being backed up.

Comment: @bdrx Noooo, why?!

Comment: Great question! We tried to archive all our projects to put them in read only mode so we could back them up and migrate our gitlab to a different machine. After running the backup and restoring on the new machine, SURPRISE, any of the projects that were archived were not there.

Answer (score 0):

To switch the whole GitLab instance to read-only mode, enable the [GitLab Maintenance Mode](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/maintenance_mode/).

To enable the GitLab Maintenance Mode from the GitLab Rails console (`sudo gitlab-rails console`):

```
::Gitlab::CurrentSettings.update!(maintenance_mode: true)
::Gitlab::CurrentSettings.update!(maintenance_mode_message: "New message")
```

Comment: It says it's a feature introduced in GitLab 13.9 but I'm upgrading a v14.5.2 and it isn't here, nor rails console works too. Check @KevinVasko comment if it's your case, It just work.